# Anakin and Obi-Wan's attack path in Episode III

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

On closer inspection, the initial attack path that Anakin and Obi-Wan use in the Battle over Coruscant make little sense:

- They fly dangerously close to the surface of several capital ships
- They fly into the debris path of large detonations
- They perform seemingly needless rolls

Is there an in-universe description or explanation of their attack tactics?

Comment: Did you not see how freaking cool that battle was? There's your answer. Also, [needless rolls are awesome](https://i.giphy.com/media/iJ5bSix01wY36/giphy.webp)

Comment: This is how a jedi fights

Comment: They were trying to gain the higher ground, probably

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html) would indicate that their plan is to "avoid flak", presumably by making their path extremely hard to track and predict. That would explain their [formation flying](https://youtu.be/jqfXXaOisKo?t=35), heading through [clouds of debris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaff_(countermeasure)) and constant desire to stick close to larger objects.

> PAN DOWN to reveal a REPUBLIC ATTACK CRUISER. Continue to PAN with the Cruiser as TWO JEDI STARFIGHTERS enter and head toward an enemy Battle Cruiser. TRUCK with the Jedi Fighters as they maneuver in unison, dodging flack and enemy laser fire. R2-D2 is on Anakin's ship. R4-P17 is on Obi-Wan's ship. A giant space battle is revealed as the tiny Jedi ships continue their assault in a synchronous ballet.
>
> 2 INT. OBI-WAN'S STARFIGHTER COCKPIT-SPACE
>
> OBI-WAN bounces through the flack with a frown. His ship rocks violently.

and

> The cruiser dropped away behind them. **Out in open space, he was a
> sitting duck.** He needed something else to dodge behind. A Separatist
> battleship loomed — not the best idea, perhaps, but the only one
> available at the moment. “I’m going down on the deck,” he told Anakin.
> **He swung his fighter, narrowly avoiding another barrage of laser fire.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

---

It's always worth pointing out that a Jedi's actions, no matter how *seemingly unneeded* are guided by the Force to find them the best route to their goal. In this case that apparently required [spinning and whirling like idiots.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TDmxHu78GY)

> New bursts of flak bracketed his path. He reached into the Force,
> feeling for a safe channel through the swarms of shrapnel and sizzling
> nets of particle beams.
>
> There wasn’t one.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: Personally I suspect that Anakin was doing it on purpose to piss Obi-Wan off.